# how to compared with BGR image pixel value in open CV?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to compare pixel value in a line like this:

```
for x in range (xRang[0] ,xRang[1]):
    y = s_p[0] + dy * (x - xRang[0])/ dx # this is line formula. s_p is start point [y,x]
        
    if(i[round(y),x] == 0 || test[round(y),x] != [255,255,255]): 
        return 0
```

I is work because gray scaled image. So pixel value is 0 or 255.

I can compare with some value.

But the test is bgr image. So in that `test[round(y),x] != [255,255,255]` if condition didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(test[round(y), x] == np.array([255, 255, 255])).sum() != 3` as the condition. I assume `test[round(y), x]` gives a `numpy` array of 3 values.

Comment: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() error occur! test[round(y), x] is bgr value like a [ 255 0 255 ]  , [111, 222 , 131 ].....something. and I just want if that test's pixel value is whether [ 255 255 255 ] or not

Comment: I don't get why it is ambiguous. You are comparing a 3 element `numpy` array with another 3 element `numpy` array. The output if the array values are equal would be an array `[True, True, True]`. So in only that case, it sums up to `3`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I understand your algorithm. Your logic is right but i don't know why there be error. I think it is BGR image and it have some different method to access value :(

Comment: Error : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: May be you try a bit debugging by printing out `test[round(y), x]` values.

Comment: value is like a [255 255 255] printed